# How to fix NumberFormatException in my controller?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am getting a `NumberFormatException` in my code. Can anyone suggest me how to overcome this? I am trying to add query based on a customer id. Customer id is join column in query table. When I click the add query link, I have to get the particular id automatically.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder1(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Customer.class,"customer", new PropertyEditorSupport() {
         @Override
        public void setAsText(String customer) {
            setValue(new Customer(Integer.parseInt(customer)));
        }
    });
}

@RequestMapping(value="/addQuery.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView reportForm1(ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request) {
    int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    System.out.println(id);

    Queries query = new Queries();
    Customer customer = new Customer(id);

    query.setCustomer(customer);
    model.addAttribute("queries", query);
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("addQuery");

    return mav;

}
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Oct 14, 2014 12:25:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path      
[/CustomerPortal] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is    
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null] with root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
  at com.axiscapstone.customer.web.CustomerController.reportForm1(CustomerController.java:86)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You should log `request.getParameter("id")` and test if it is null before parsing it. You can also use a debugger to control that.

Comment: thank you for response. but am new to Spring. so can u show how to log

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring.  when you attempt to parse a null using parseInt() you will get a null pointer exception.

Comment: You should learn how to use a logger such as Apache commons logging or better slf4j, it is always useful. But for now, you could just use `Object obj = request.getParameter("id")); System.err.printl("param[id] : " + (obj == null ? "<NULL>" : obj.toString());` as first line of method `CustomerController.reportForm1`

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346192/am-getting-this-error-in-controller, isn't it ? Please **DO NOT REPEAT SAME QUESTION** but update first one or delete it.

Comment: ok...thank you... i'll learn that. . but still nothing happened after adding it also   :(

Comment: yes. i posted that first..no one responded.. so i rewrite the post... now i deleted the first post

Comment: Evidently id is not present as request parameter. So somewhere there is a wrong addQuery link missing an id.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this conversion by yourself. Let Spring do it:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addQuery.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView reportForm1(@RequestParam Integer id, ModelMap model) {
    System.out.println(id);
    ...
```

But id is of type Integer, which can of course be null.
You can force client to provide this URL parameter by using `@RequestParam(required = true)`

Comment: So without writing @RequestParam Integer id.... i should replace with this @RequestParam(required = true)?

Comment: @user3599302 yes. The effect would be that client gets some error when id parameter will be missing

Comment: after adding that as u suggested i got error as HTTP Status 400 - Required Integer parameter 'id' is not present

type

Comment: that is exactly what you want if you need to force client to specify id URL parameter. If id can be unspecified, you need to handle null id in your code

Comment: in console am getting the Id of the customer... but in web page am getting HTTP Status 400 - Required Integer parameter 'id' is not present type

Comment: if you remove ``(required = true)`` you wouldn't get 400 error, but id will be null

Comment: try to append to request: ``?id=1``

Comment: HTTP Status 400 - Required Integer parameter 'id' is not present

type Status report

message Required Integer parameter 'id' is not present

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Am new to spring. so can u show the how to write and where to write

Comment: I suspect you are unfamiliar with URL parameters. Please take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string. If you send request this request ``.../addQuery.htm?id=1``, your id parameter in Java will be 1.

Comment: yes it is mandatory. when ever a customer want to add a query , the customers id should automatically come in the customer id fields..and other fields will be entered by the customer regarding query and submit it. when customer submit the query details should be added to db under his id only but in url it is not getting ?id=1 and showing error as mentioned in above comment

Comment: But when i forcely write in the URL ?id=1 the Id is getting perfectly..but when i run project am not getting it :(

Comment: Don't understand this: "..but when i run project am not getting it :("

Comment: i said when i manually wrote ?id=1 am getting the Id as 1 in the customer id field. but when i run the project and click on addQuery in the url it is stopping at http://localhost:6001/CustomerPortal/customer/addQuery.htm

Comment: But this is totally different story how your URL is generated when you click in your portal. Sorry I am giving up.

Comment: if u have teamviewer u can see what's happeneing...can u able to come in team viewer?